# scanf statement in c and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I read many previous questions but none of them cleared my doubt.
When I define and initialize a pointer as

```
int a = 10;
int* p;
p = &a;
printf("%d", *p); // this will print the value of 'a' towards which p is pointing
```

But when I use scanf statement like-

```
int *p;
scanf("%d", &p);
printf("%d", p); // is this form of input similar to the one above?
```

Also when I use char pointer to read a string-

```
char* name[10];
scanf("%s", name);
printf("%s", name); // runs correctly.
```

What I know is that scanf expects pointer as input (like `&a` if it's like `int a;`)
But If I use--

```
char* names[5][10];
scanf("%s", names[1]); // reading the first name. Is this correct? because length of name can vary.
```

Now I am unable to print this, I tried no of ways.
A detailed explanation would be appreciated, my teacher isn't that good.
**DOUBTS**

- When do we use `*` with a pointer? i.e. to print its value or for what?
- Unable to scan `char* xyz[a][b];`
- A brief explanation of my mistakes and the code above.
  Edits-

  int* arr[n];
  for(int i =0; i<n; i++){
  printf("Enter the salary of %d person:", i+1);
  scanf("%d", &(arr[i]));
  printf("\n");
  }

Also, this type of assignment of value is not right?

Comment: There are few parallels between the working `printf()` and the `scanf()` code, which should fail horribly.  You're asking the user to enter a valid address as a decimal number, assuming that `sizeof(int *) == sizeof(int)` which is usually not the case on 64-bit systems.  You're then printing the pointer entered using an inappropriate format.  It's hard to know why you think there are useful analogies between the two.

Comment: The `char *name[10];` defines an array of pointers; you've not defined any storage that those pointers point at.  Reading a string while passing the name of the array of pointers is completely bogus.  You annotate that it runs correctly – that's surprising, but not actually impossible.  It is, however, undefined behaviour and that means anything can happen, including appearing to work.  But it is 100% unreliable.

Comment: try with float pointer and %f...

Comment: The `char* names[5][10];` example is still weirder.  You should be using a compiler that complains bitterly about the mismatches between your format strings and the variables passed to `scanf()`.  If your compiler doesn't complain (when tweaked with suitable arguments to increase the warning levels), then you shoulds get a better compiler.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So I should only limit the use of pointers to store the memory address not anything else. Actually, we have some assignments in which they ask us to only use pointers. I use gnu gcc compiler. I should not store values in pointers directly using `scanf` ryt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   printf("%d", p); // is this form of input similar to the one above?
```

no, `%d` expects an `int` argument, you're passing an `int *`. Supplying mismatched argument type for a conversion specifier invokes undefined behaviour.

That said, in case of

```
char* name[10];      // array of character pointers!
scanf("%s", name);
printf("%s", name); // runs correctly.
```

you're going wrong. Check the data types. `%s` expects the argument to be a pointer to a `char` array, so your code should be

```
char name[10];        // array of characters
scanf("%9s", name);  // mandatory error check for success to be done.
printf("%s", name);
```

as, in most of the cases including this one, an array type decays to the pointer to the first element of the array, so while passing as function argument, `name` is actually of type `char *`.

Same goes with

```
char* names[5][10];
scanf("%s", names[1]);
```

changing that to

```
char names[5][10];
```

will suffice.

Comment: Can you explain the last point a bit more? If I am getting it right the reference variable `name` is of the type `char*`.

Comment: @PrithvirajYadav Which part? array decay? you can check [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432)

Comment: You don't seem to get the point: **Check the data types!**

Comment: No I got the point, I am just saying, that is also not correct.

Comment: I got what you were saying about format specefier

Comment: They why do you write (in your latest example) `int* arr[n];` and not `int arr[n];`? See, all format specifiers have a required type, ensure you supply that proper type and nothing else.

Comment: I was just confirming that it is incorrect :-)